# Ad mob for windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, admob

I just registered an admob account, but I am developing apps for windows phone 7, I don't see any SDK for windows phone 7 on their website. They only offer SDK for windows phone 8. How can I integrate ad mob into my windows phone 7 apps?

Answer (score 0):

To get the SDK for WP7. Log into to your admob account and adding a site type of Windows Phone 7.

Hopefully that helps.

http://googlemobileads.blogspot.ca/2011/03/new-beta-admob-windows-phone-7-sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

The new AdMob doesn't support Windows Phone 7 apps. Google deprecated Windows Phone 7 in August 2013 : https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3369601?hl=en-GB

still You can configure AdMob but Sometimes it gets Crashes in your Applicatioin so it would better to use Microsoft's Pubcenter ads.

for more Refrence you can go [here](http://joshearl.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/using-display-ads-in-windows-phone-7-apps/)